# COM dispinterface events

Tags: c++, com

I am a COM beginner and trying to use a managed library in my c++ project through COM.. I could able to create instance for the dual interfaces and call methods... it is working fine...

I would like to know how to construct client interface which can receive events from any dispinterface COM object ?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#import "../COMLib/bin/Debug/COMLib.tlb" named_guids
#include <comutil.h>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
CoInitialize(NULL);

COMLib::ICalcPtr pCalc;

HRESULT hRes = pCalc.CreateInstance(__uuidof(COMLib::Calc));
if(FAILED(hRes))
    printf("ICalcPtr::CreateInstance failed w/err 0x%08lx\n", hRes);
else
{
    printf("%d\n", pCalc->Factorial(10));
}

CoUninitialize();
return 0;
}
```

I know how to create instance for dual interface like above. But I need help to instantiate dispinterface for events. Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: "Working fine" - so what _is_ the question?

Comment: working for dual interface. Don't know how to create instance for a dispinterface. I have to  receive events from the dispinterface.

Comment: The trick with understanding COM is to be clear that you don't create an instance of an interface. You create an instance of a CoClass and then QueryInterface for whatever you need/the CoClass implements. You are not creating an instance of a dispinterface. You are accessing the dispinterface of an already created instance of something.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms690572%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Once you have you Com instance just go ahead and [queryinterface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221037%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for any further interfaces you need to use. Assuming it implements IDispatch you'll have a pointer to that interface.

```
COMLib::ICalcPtr pCalc;

HRESULT hRes = pCalc.CreateInstance(__uuidof(COMLib::Calc));
if(FAILED(hRes))
    printf("ICalcPtr::CreateInstance failed w/err 0x%08lx\n", hRes);
else
{
    IDispatchPtr pDisp;
    hRes = pCalc->QueryInterface(IID_IDispatch, &pDisp);
    ASSERT(SUCCEEDED(hRes));

    printf("%d\n", pCalc->Factorial(10));

}
```

If you are looking to sink COM events from this object you probably really want the [IConnectionPoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms694318%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) set of interfaces. [This article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3541/COM-Connection-Points) has good explanation and examples of how to attach to and sink connection point events from COM objects in C++.

Comment: Thanks dkackman... I am looking for a good start point for the IConnectionPoint set of interfaces. I have one dispinterface with some events and I want the events to be fired on client side.

Comment: Start with the codeproject link above and then there's plenty of examples on the interwebs.